# update a random row and get the row result back in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `pcodes` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `used` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and an insert command is the following:

```
INSERT INTO `pcodes` (`product_id`, `code`) VALUES ('1', 'test2');
```

The table contains random codes for each product_id. I want to get one unused code randomly (LIMIT 1 is ok for the job), mark the code as used and return it to the next layer.

So far I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM pcodes where product_id=1 and used=0 LIMIT 1
UPDATE pcodes SET used= 1 WHERE (id = 2);
```

but this does not work well when multiple threads request the first unused code. What is the optimal solution to do this query? I would like to avoid stored procedures.

Comment: MySQL cannot update and select in one query - so you need 2 separate queries. `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` and then `UPDATE`. If you need to check does the update was succcessful then you need 3rd query.

Comment: Does `used` column may contain the values other than used in your code `0` and `1`?

Comment: @Akina no there wll be no other values. used =1 or 0 (not used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution.

Assumes that there aren't other predefined values stored in `used` column except `0` and `1`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_one_random_row (OUT rowid BIGINT)
BEGIN
    REPEAT
        UPDATE pcodes SET used = CONNECTION_ID() WHERE used = 0 LIMIT 1;
        SELECT id INTO rowid FROM pcodes WHERE used = CONNECTION_ID();
    UNTIL rowid IS NOT NULL END REPEAT;
    UPDATE pcodes SET used = 1 WHERE used = CONNECTION_ID();
END
```

To prevent indefinite loop (for example when no rows with `used=0`) add some counter which increments in REPEAT cycle and breaks it after some reasonable iteration attempts.

The code may be converted to FUNCTION which returns selected `rowid`.

It is possible that the procedure/function fails (by some external reasons), and a row will stay "selected by current CONNECTION_ID()" whereas the connection is broken itself. So you need in service procedure executed by Event Scheduler which will garbage the rows which belongs to non-existed connections and clear their `used` value back to zero returning such rows to unused pool.

Comment: Hi Akina, this solution looks good, however I would prefer to avoid procedures and do it in the process.

Comment: @malefstro Nothing prevents you to use inner statements without a cycle as single attempt to reserve the row.

Comment: got you know. Update the used with a unique known value and then get the row using the unique known value. Nice trick.